# PSTricks: y-axis spacing not consistent when 0.005

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I am trying to make a graph where the y-axis starts at 0.99 and increments in steps of 0.005 to 1.001. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=32pt, 10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\psset{xAxisLabel=$\Omega_s$, yAxisLabel=$\theta$}



\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame, Dx=10, Dy=0.005, Oy={0.99}, Ox={0}](0,0.99)(100,1.01){7.0cm}{6.0cm}%

\end{psgraph}    
\end{document}
```

This creates a y-axis that starts at 0.99, but is then followed by 0.104, 0.109, 1.114 etc., even though I set the spacing and reference to the desired values. The location of the x-axis label is also increased, so it "hovers".

This is not the first time I experience this when having y-axes with small values. Is there a way to fix the incrementation and the axes labels such that they appear right beside (x) and above (y) the axes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same numer of decimals for `Dy` and `Oy`: 0.005 and 0.990

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=32pt, 10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\psset{xAxisLabel=$\Omega_s$, yAxisLabel=$\theta$}
\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame, Dx=10, Dy=0.005, 
    Oy=0.990, Ox=0](0,0.99)(100,1.01){7.0cm}{6.0cm}     
\end{psgraph}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue of the numbering. The axes labels are still weird though. Is there a way to position them next to the axes (x) and above for (y)?

Comment: there are a lot of examples in the documentation of `pst-plot`